# how to load fnt format fonts in ios application

Tags: iphone, ios, uikit, uifont

i want to load a .fnt format fonts in my application, i tried using the same technique as i load .ttf fonts, but it doesnot work.

```
+(UIFont *) orangeFontWithSize:(int) size
{
    return [UIFont fontWithName:@"orange-font.fnt" size:size];
}
```

please help regarding this.
thanks

Comment: Did you copy the font to your project and add a reference in your info.plist?

Comment: yes, i added the entry in plist but the fonts still not coming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.fnt font files are not currently supported in iOS apps.